# How can I keep this text on the same line

Tags: css, html-table

Simply I have two bits of text on the line

Kroppspoäng and also (sty+kyl)

But they have moved to different lines

```
 <td class="sheet-table-invis2">
                                <h4 data-i18n="hit-points">Kroppspo&auml;ng</h4><h5 data-i18n="strength-agility">(sty+kyl)</h5>
                            </td>
```

Comment: td h4, td h5 {display:inline-block}

Comment: It might be best to avoid creating the problem in the first place. It is created by the use of heading elements inside a table cell. What are they headings for, when the cell contains nothing else? Consider using e.g. `span` elements with suitable style settings instead.

Comment: So how do I change text size with a span tag?

Answer (score 2):

The `h4` and `h5` are `block` elements, so their widths will take up the width of their parent and stack on top of one another as rows. To display them inline with one another, make them `inline-block`

```css
h4,h5 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<td class="sheet-table-invis2">
  <h4 data-i18n="hit-points">Kroppspo&auml;ng</h4>
  <h5 data-i18n="strength-agility">(sty+kyl)</h5>
</td>
```

You can also make the parent `flex` and the default direction will be a `row`

```css
.sheet-table-invis2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="sheet-table-invis2">
    <h4 data-i18n="hit-points">Kroppspo&auml;ng</h4>
    <h5 data-i18n="strength-agility">(sty+kyl)</h5>
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a `display: flex` CSS rule as this isn't supported at all in IE9 or fully supported in IE10. These browser version are still very popular.

Instead, I'd suggest using the `white-space: nowrap` and `display:inline-block` CSS rules per the code below so IE9, IE10, and all other popular browsers are supported.

```css
.sheet-table-invis2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sheet-table-invis2 h4, .sheet-table-invis2 h5 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="sheet-table-invis2">
    <h4 data-i18n="hit-points">Kroppspo&auml;ng</h4><h5 data-i18n="strength-agility">(sty+kyl)</h5>
  </td>
</table>
```